# Regular Expression to split on specific character ONLY if that character is not in a pair

Tags: python, regex, string, replace

After finding the fastest string replace algorithm in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1919096/mass-string-replace-in-python), I've been trying to modify one of them to suit my needs, particularly [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1919096/mass-string-replace-in-python/1919221#1919221) by gnibbler.

I will explain the problem again here, and what issue I am having.

Say I have a string that looks like this:

```
str = "The &yquick &cbrown &bfox &Yjumps over the &ulazy dog"
```

You'll notice a lot of locations in the string where there is an ampersand, followed by a character (such as "&y" and "&c"). I need to replace these characters with an appropriate value that I have in a dictionary, like so:

```
dict = {"y":"\033[0;30m",
        "c":"\033[0;31m",
        "b":"\033[0;32m",
        "Y":"\033[0;33m",
        "u":"\033[0;34m"}
```

Using gnibblers solution provided in my previous thread, I have this as my current solution:

```
myparts = tmp.split('&')
myparts[1:]=[dict.get(x[0],"&"+x[0])+x[1:] for x in myparts[1:]]
result = "".join(myparts)
```

This works for replacing the characters properly, and does not fail on characters that are not found.  The only problem with this is that there is no simple way to **actually** keep an ampersand in the output.  The easiest way I could think of would be to change my dictionary to contain:

```
dict = {"y":"\033[0;30m",
        "c":"\033[0;31m",
        "b":"\033[0;32m",
        "Y":"\033[0;33m",
        "u":"\033[0;34m",
        "&":"&"}
```

And change my "split" call to do a regex split on ampersands that are NOT followed by other ampersands.

```
>>> import re
>>> tmp = "&yI &creally &blove A && W &uRootbeer."
>>> tmp.split('&')
['', 'yI ', 'creally ', 'blove A ', '', ' W ', 'uRootbeer.']
>>> re.split('MyRegex', tmp)
['', 'yI ', 'creally ', 'blove A ', '&W ', 'uRootbeer.']
```

Basically, I need a Regex that will split on the **first ampersand of a pair**, and every **single** ampersand, to allow me to escape it via my dictionary.

If anyone has any better solutions please feel free to let me know.

Comment: Mike, I'm a little puzzled (though not personally hurt) why you don't use my solution from that other question.  It turned out to be the fastest on real data, *does* have the property of keeping actual ampersands in the output, and is certainly among the most readable of the answers given.

Comment: Peter:  The reason for that is that I had not yet read your comment on why I was receiving the errors I was, and wasn't able to find a solution by the time I needed to write this code.  Now that I see your comments, it's likely that I'll switch the code to use your faster, more readable solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a negative lookbehind (assuming the regex engine in question supports it) to only match ampersands that do not follow another ampersand.

```
/(?<!&)&/
```

Comment: This worked perfectly.  I don't know what kind of speed sacrifices I'm making by doing a lookbehind, so if anyone can come up with a more efficient solution (if it even exists), I'll be glad to hear it.

Comment: As noted above in comment to your question, my solution is actually faster than gnibbler's even before you change it to use a regex split.  In any case, I included test code with correct simulated input that should easily let you benchmark the performance change if you stick with this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe loop while (q = str.find('&', p)) != -1, then append the left side (p + 2 to q - 1) and the replacement value.

Answer (score 0):

I think this does the trick:

```
import re

def fix(text):
    dict = {"y":"\033[0;30m",
            "c":"\033[0;31m",
            "b":"\033[0;32m",
            "Y":"\033[0;33m",
            "u":"\033[0;34m",
            "&":"&"}

    myparts = re.split('\&(\&*)', text)
    myparts[1:]=[dict.get(x[0],"&"+x[0])+x[1:] if len(x) > 0 else x for x in myparts[1:]]
    result = "".join(myparts)
    return result


print fix("The &yquick &cbrown &bfox &Yjumps over the &ulazy dog")
print fix("&yI &creally &blove A && W &uRootbeer.")
```

Answer (score 0):

re.sub will do what you want.  It takes a regex pattern and can take a function to process the match and return the replacement.  Below if the character following the & is not in the dictionary, no replacement is made.  && is replaced with & to allow escaping an & that is followed by a character in the dictionary.

Also 'str' and 'dict' are bad variables names because they shadow the built-in functions of the same name.

In 's' below, '& cat' will not be affected and '&&cat' will become "&cat" suppressing &c translation.

```
import re

s = "The &yquick &cbrown &bfox & cat &&cat &Yjumps over the &ulazy dog"

D = {"y":"\033[0;30m",
     "c":"\033[0;31m",
     "b":"\033[0;32m",
     "Y":"\033[0;33m",
     "u":"\033[0;34m",
     "&":"&"}

def func(m):
    return D.get(m.group(1),m.group(0))

print repr(re.sub(r'&(.)',func,s))
```

OUTPUT:

```
'The \x1b[0;30mquick \x1b[0;31mbrown \x1b[0;32mfox & cat &cat \x1b[0;33mjumps over the \x1b[0;34mlazy dog'
```

-Mark