# RegEx to Reject Unescaped HTML Character

Tags: html, xml, regex, escaping, ampersand

I want to restrict usage of unescaped ampersands in a particular input field. I'm having trouble getting a RegEx to kill usage of "&" unless followed by "amp;"...or perhaps just restrict usage of "& " (note the space).

I tried to adapt the answer [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936837/regular-expression-to-split-on-specific-character-only-if-that-character-is-not-i), but to no avail. Thanks.

(FWIW, here's a RegEx I made to ensure that a filename field didn't contain restrited chars. and ended in .mp3. It works fine, but does it look efficient?)

```
^[^&,<,>,:,",/,\\,|,?,\*]+(\.mp3|\.MP3|\.Mp3|\.mP3)$
```

Comment: Where's the link to your regex?

Comment: do you also want to allow e.g. the german a umlaut &auml;? Or other international characters?

Comment: @John - Apprently it got stripped out without me noticing....will try again.

@Soren - Those chars. won't be a problem for me, but feel free to show how for others who may see this question later.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This regular expression matches any occurrence of `&` which is not followed by `amp;`:

```
/&(?!amp;)/
```

[Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/DH8zonNp3Q)

This regular expression accepts strings that contain characters except `&`, or the string `&amp;`:

```
/^([^&]|&amp;)*$/
```

[Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/IO2ltyo0lU)

You can use either one or the other, depending on which is most convenient. The difference is that the string should be *rejected* if the first regular expression matches, whereas the string should be *accepted* if the second regular expression matches.

Comment: OK. I wasn't using the | "or" & also grouped improperly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can match on `/&(?!amp;)/` to locate any &'s not followed by &amp. The (?!) construction is called a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Assuming you're using a regexp engine that supports them, at any rate. I know Perl/PCRE regexps do.