# How to replace all strings in python?

Tags: python, html, string, parsing

I am creating a proxy scraper using reguler experessions. Html parsing with re is terrible, so I need to make sure no strings show up in the end result. How can I replace all strings with a space. The current code I had to clean up the parsed data was

```
print title.replace(',', '').replace("!", '').replace(":", '').replace(";", '').replace(str, '')
```

The str portion was what I tried.... it did not work. Any other methods?

Comment: [Obligatory](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1223693). Use an HTML parsing library, such as BeautifulSoup.

Comment: *“Html parsing with re is terrible”* – Regular expressions were never meant to parse HTML; and HTML isn’t designed to be parsable by regular expressions to begin with.

Comment: The pony. He comes...

Comment: Try here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10017147/python-replace-characters-in-string

Comment: *“make sure no strings show up”*, *“replace all strings”*, *“str portion was what I tried”* – What *strings* are you even referring to? How do you want to replace *all strings*? What *all strings*? If I replace all strings *in a string* with a space, I get just a space back.

Comment: I have the sourceCode for the website. I want to keep all intergers but get rid of all strings

Comment: @Ungifted So you actually want to *extract numbers*? Which numbers do you care about? *All of them* or just those numbers that are displayed somewhere? (There could be numbers in HTML attributes for example, or somewhere else in the code).

Comment: `print " "` - if you replace all strings with a space, whatever your definition of string is, then this is what you get after applying this replacement over and over again

Comment: I removed  the tags... Now I got a mix of data. Words and numbers. I need only the numbers

Comment: @poke All the numbers present. Only numbers

Comment: @poke I want to do this just using reguler expressions

Comment: @Ungifted No, you don’t want to do that, for all the reasons me and others mentioned in the comments.

Comment: @poke I cant install beautiful soup? I looked up tutorials and not one is working? I have a windows computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
replace1 = range(0,46)+range(58,127)+[47] #Makes a list of all the 
#ASCII characters  values that you don't want it to show,
#http://www.asciitable.com/, this includes all the letters,
#and excludes all numbers and '.'

text = '<html><body><p>127.0.0.1</p></body></html>' #Test data.
tmp = '' 

for i in range(len(text)-1): #this goes through each character in the text
...     if not ord(text[i]) in replace1: #checks if that character's 
#ASCII value is in not the list of 'Blacklisted' ASCII values, 
#then appends it to the tmp variable 
...             tmp += text[i]

print tmp
127.0.0.1
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to extract all *visible* numbers from the HTML document, you can first use BeautifulSoup to parse the HTML document, and extract the text from it. And after that, you can extract all the numbers from those text elements:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
import re

# let’s use the StackOverflow homepage as an example
r = urlopen('http://stackoverflow.com')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r)

# As we don’t want to get the content from script related
# elements, remove those.
for script in soup(['script', 'noscript']):
    script.extract()

# And now extract the numbers using regular expressions from
# all text nodes we can find in the (remaining) document.
numbers = [n for t in soup(text=True) for n in re.findall('\d+', t)]
```

`numbers` will then contain all the numbers that were visible in the document. If you want to restrict the search to only certain elements, you can change the `soup(text=True)` part.