# Python - removing everything from a string except certain characters

Tags: python

Not sure if this question has been asked before, but I couldn't find it, so here it is:

```
randomList = ["ACGT","A#$..G","..,/\]AGC]]]T"]
randomList2 = []
for i in randomList:
  if i <contains any characters other than "A",C","G", or "T">:
    <add a string without junk to randomList2>
```

How would I do all the things within <>?
Thanks,

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10017169/2282538

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> randomList = ["ACGT","A#$..G","..,/\]AGC]]]T"]
>>> import re
>>> [re.sub("[^ACGT]+", "", s) for s in randomList]
['ACGT', 'AG', 'AGCT']
```

`[^ACGT]+` matches one or more (`+`)  characters except `ACGT`.

Some timings:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> setup = '''randomList = ["ACGT","A#$..G","..,/\]AGC]]]T"]
... import re'''
>>> timeit.timeit(setup=setup, stmt='[re.sub("[^ACGT]+", "", s) for s in randomList]')
8.197133132976195
>>> timeit.timeit(setup=setup, stmt='[re.sub("[^ACGT]", "", s) for s in randomList]')
9.395620040786165
```

Without `re`, it's faster (see @cmd's answer):

```
>>> timeit.timeit(setup=setup, stmt="[''.join(c for c in s if c in 'ACGT') for s in randomList]")
6.874829817476666
```

Even faster (see @JonClement's comment):

```
>>> setup='''randomList = ["ACGT","A#$..G","..,/\]AGC]]]T"]\nascii_exclude = ''.join(set('ACGT').symmetric_difference(map(chr, range(256))))'''
>>> timeit.timeit(setup=setup, stmt="""[item.translate(None, ascii_exclude) for item in randomList]""")
2.814761871275735
```

Also possible:

```
>>> setup='randomList = ["ACGT","A#$..G","..,/\]AGC]]]T"]'
>>> timeit.timeit(setup=setup, stmt="[filter(set('ACGT').__contains__, item) for item in randomList]")
4.341086316883207
```

Comment: Don't think the `+` needs to be there...

Comment: @JonClements: It speeds up the match because the characters don't have to be replaced one by one. Will add some timings.

Comment: While it does make sense, for simple char replacements I wouldn't have thought there'd be such a difference. Thanks for taking the time to post the `timeit`s.

Comment: I would be curious to see how something such as: `ascii_exclude = ''.join(set('ACGT').symmetric_difference(map(chr, range(256)))); for item in randomList: print item.translate(None, ascii_exclude)` performs...

Comment: Possibly also the rather nasty (but avoids a join)... `filter(set('ACGT').__contains__, the_string)`

Comment: @JonClements: I added the timings. Excellent ideas! Well, I'm off to bed now. G'night.

Answer (score 4):

`re` is overkill for this

```
randomList2 = [''.join(c for c in s if c in 'ACGT') for s in randomList]
```

and if you dont want the ones that didn't initially have junk

```
valid = set("ACGT")
randomList2 = [''.join(c for c in s if c in valid) for s in randomList if any(c2 not in valid for c2 in s)]
```

Comment: Good point, and very elegant. Also faster (see my edited answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions:

```
import re
randomList = ["ACGT","A#$..G","..,/\]AGC]]]T"]
nonACGT = re.compile('[^ACGT]')
for i in range(len(randomList)):
    randomList[i] = nonACGT.sub('', randomList[i])
print randomList
```