# Replace Characters in a string Python

Tags: python, replace

I am looking for a way to replace a characters in a sentence, given that we have:

```
sentence = "hello - world!: ¡hola - mundo"
```

I need to be it like that -> hello world hola mundo

I can do

```
sentence.replace('!' , '' )
sentence.replace(':' , '' )
.
.
.
```

But it doesn't seems a good solution

so far i have this, but it doesn't replace what I want:

```
for ch in ["!",":"]:
        if ch in sentence:
            sentence = sentence.replace(ch," " + ch)
```

any suggestions how to make it work? 
Thank you.

Comment: There's a good discussion of this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10017147/python-replace-characters-in-string

Answer (score 0):

You can make a `set` of all characters you want to keep, then use a generator expression to keep all those letters. Or conversely a `set` of characters to be removed and keep everything but those. The [`string` library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) has some useful things for this, e.g. `string.ascii_lowercase` or `string.punctuation`.

```
>>> import string
>>> keep = set(string.ascii_lowercase + string.ascii_uppercase + ' ')

>>> ''.join(i for i in sentence if i in keep)
'hello  world hola  mundo'
```

Answer (score 0):

you can split your sentence with none alphabet characters and join those that have `len>0` for refuse `''`:

```
>>> import re
>>> ' '.join([i for i in re.split(r'\W',sentence) if len(i)])
'hello world hola mundo'
```