# using strip() in python

Tags: python, strip

Write the function list_of_words that takes a list of strings as above and returns a list of individual words with all white space and punctuation removed (except for apostrophes/single quotes).

My code removes periods and spaces, but not commas or exclamation points.

```
def list_of_words(list_str):
    m = []
    for i in list_str:
        i.strip('.')
        i.strip(',')
        i.strip('!')
        m = m+i.split()
    return m

print(list_of_words(["Four score and seven years ago, our fathers brought forth on",
  "this continent a new nation, conceived in liberty and dedicated",
  "to the proposition that all men are created equal.  Now we are",
  "   engaged in a great        civil war, testing whether that nation, or any",
  "nation so conceived and so dedicated, can long endure!"])
```

Comment: I need to use the strip() or split() method, not the replace method.

Comment: The short version: `return [word.strip('.,!') for part in list_str for word in part.split()]`

Answer (score 2):

One of the easiest way to clear some punctuation marks and multiple whitespaces would be using [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) function.

```
import re

sentence_list = ["Four score and seven years ago, our fathers brought forth on",
                 "this continent a new nation, conceived in liberty and dedicated",
                 "to the proposition that all men are created equal.  Now we are",
                 "   engaged in a great        civil war, testing whether that nation, or any",
                 "nation so conceived and so dedicated, can long endure!"]

sentences = [re.sub('([,.!]){1,}', '', sentence).strip() for sentence in sentence_list]
words = ' '.join([re.sub('([" "]){2,}', ' ', sentence).strip() for sentence in sentences])

print words
"Four score and seven years ago our fathers brought forth on this continent a new nation conceived in liberty and dedicated to the proposition that all men are created equal Now we are engaged in a great civil war testing whether that nation or any nation so conceived and so dedicated can long endure"
```

Answer (score 1):

`strip` returns the string, you should catch and apply the remaining strips.
so your code should be changed to

```
for i in list_str:
    i = i.strip('.')
    i = i.strip(',')
    i = i.strip('!')
    ....
```

on second note, `strip` removes the mentioned characters only on start and end of strings. If you want to remove characters in-between the string, you should consider `replace`

Answer (score 1):

You could use regular expressions, as explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10017147/python-replace-characters-in-string?s=1%7C3.5872). Essentially,

```py
import re

i = re.sub('[.,!]', '', i)
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested before, you need to assign the `i.strip()` to `i`. And as mentioned before, the replace method is better. Here is an example using the replace method:

```
def list_of_words(list_str:list)->list:
    m=[]
    for i in list_str:
        i = i.replace('.','')
        i = i.replace(',','')
        i = i.replace('!','')
        m.extend(i.split())
    return m

print(list_of_words([ "Four score and seven years ago, our fathers brought forth on",
  "this continent a new nation, conceived in liberty and dedicated",
  "to the proposition that all men are created equal.  Now we are",
  "   engaged in a great        civil war, testing whether that nation, or any",
  "nation so conceived and so dedicated, can long endure! ])
```

As you can notice, I have also replaced `m=m+i.split()` with `m.append(i.split())` to make it easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better not to rely on your own list of punctuation, but use python's one and as others have pointer, use regex to remove chars:

```
punctuations = re.sub("[`']", "", string.punctuation)
i = re.sub("[" + punctuations + "]", "", i)
```

There's also `string.whitespace`, although split does take care of them for you.