# Change Letters in A String One at a Time (Pandas,Python3)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a list of words in Pandas (DF)

```
Words
Shirt
Blouse
Sweater
```

What I'm trying to do is swap out certain letters in those words with letters from my dictionary **one letter at a time**.

so for example:

```
mydict = {"e":"q,w",
          "a":"z"}
```

would create a new list that first replaces all the "e" in a list one at a time, and then iterates through again replacing all the "a" one at a time:

```
Words
Shirt
Blouse
Sweater
Blousq
Blousw
Swqater
Swwater
Sweatqr
Sweatwr
Swezter
```

I've been looking around at solutions here: [Mass string replace in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1919096/mass-string-replace-in-python)

and have tried the following code but it changes all instances "e" instead of doing so one at a time -- any help?:

```
mydict = {"e":"q,w"}
s = DF
for k, v in mydict.items():
    for j in v:
          s['Words'] = s["Words"].str.replace(k, j)
DF["Words"] = s
```

this doesn't seem to work either:

```
s = DF.replace({"Words": {"e": "q","w"}})
```

Comment: is it intentional, that `Shirt` appears twice and `Sweater` is missing in the output?

Comment: Good catch, was a mistake.  Updated the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is very similar to Brian's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28706233/2395605), but a little bit sanitized and the output has no duplicates:

```
words = ["Words", "Shirt", "Blouse", "Sweater"]
md = {"e": "q,w", "a": "z"}
md = {k: v.split(',') for k, v in md.items()}

newwords = []

for word in words:
    newwords.append(word)
    for c in md:
        occ = word.count(c)
        pos = 0
        for _ in range(occ):
            pos = word.find(c, pos)
            for r in md[c]:
                tmp = word[:pos] + r + word[pos+1:]
                newwords.append(tmp)
            pos += 1
```

Content of `newwords`:

```
['Words', 'Shirt', 'Blouse', 'Blousq', 'Blousw', 'Sweater', 'Swqater', 'Swwater', 'Sweatqr', 'Sweatwr', 'Swezter']
```

Prettyprint:

```
Words
Shirt
Blouse
Blousq
Blousw
Sweater
Swqater
Swwater
Sweatqr
Sweatwr
Swezter
```

*Any errors are a result of the current time. ;)*

---

## Update (explanation)

> **tl;dr**
>
> The main idea is to find the occurences of the character in the word one after another. For each occurence we are then replacing it with the replacing-char (again one after another). The replaced word get's added to the output-list.

I will try to explain everything step by step:

```
words = ["Words", "Shirt", "Blouse", "Sweater"]
md = {"e": "q,w", "a": "z"}
```

Well. Your basic input. :)

```
md = {k: v.split(',') for k, v in md.items()}
```

A simpler way to deal with replacing-dictionary. `md` now looks like `{"e": ["q", "w"], "a": ["z"]}`. Now we don't have to handle `"q,w"` and `"z"` differently but the step for replacing is just the same and ignores the fact, that `"a"` only got one replace-char.

```
newwords = []
```

The new list to store the output in.

```
for word in words:
    newwords.append(word)
```

We have to do those actions for each word (I assume, the reason is clear). We also append the world directly to our just created output-list (`newwords`).

```
    for c in md:
```

`c` as short for `character`. So for each character we want to replace (all keys of `md`), we do the following stuff.

```
        occ = word.count(c)
```

`occ` for `occurrences` (yeah. `count` would fit as well :P). `word.count(c)` returns the number of occurences of the character/string `c` in `word`. So `"Sweater".count("o") => 0` and `"Sweater".count("e") => 2`.
We use this here to know, how often we have to take a look at `word` to get all those occurences of `c`.

```
        pos = 0
```

Our startposition to look for `c` in `word`. Comes into use in the next loop.

```
        for _ in range(occ):
```

For each occurence. As a continual number has no value for us here, we "discard" it by naming it `_`. At this point where `c` is in `word`. Yet.

```
            pos = word.find(c, pos)
```

Oh. Look. We found `c`. :) `word.find(c, pos)` returns the index of the first occurence of `c` in `word`, starting at `pos`. At the beginning, this means from the start of the string => the first occurence of `c`. But with this call we already update `pos`. This plus the last line (`pos += 1`) moves our search-window for the next round to start just behind the previous occurence of `c`.

```
            for r in md[c]:
```

Now you see, why we updated `mc` previously: we can easily iterate over it now (a `md[c].split(',')` on the old `md` would do the job as well). So we are doing the replacement now for each of the replacement-characters.

```
                tmp = word[:pos] + r + word[pos+1:]
```

The actual replacement. We store it in `tmp` (for debug-reasons). `word[:pos]` gives us `word` up to the (current) occurence of `c` (exclusive `c`). `r` is the replacement. `word[pos+1:]` adds the remaining word (again without `c`).

```
                newwords.append(tmp)
```

Our so created new word `tmp` now goes into our output-list (`newwords`).

```
            pos += 1
```

The already mentioned adjustment of `pos` to "jump over `c`".

---

**Additional question from OP:** *Is there an easy way to dictate how many letters in the string I want to replace [(meaning e.g. multiple at a time)]?*

Surely. <strike>But I have currently only a vague idea on how to achieve this. I am going to look at it, when I got my sleep. ;)</strike>

```
words = ["Words", "Shirt", "Blouse", "Sweater", "multipleeee"]
md = {"e": "q,w", "a": "z"}
md = {k: v.split(',') for k, v in md.items()}
num = 2     # this is the number of replaces at a time.

newwords = []

for word in words:
    newwords.append(word)
    for char in md:
        for r in md[char]:
            pos = multiples = 0
            current_word = word
            while current_word.find(char, pos) != -1:
                pos = current_word.find(char, pos)
                current_word = current_word[:pos] + r + current_word[pos+1:]
                pos += 1
                multiples += 1
                if multiples == num:
                    newwords.append(current_word)
                    multiples = 0
                    current_word = word
```

Content of `newwords`:

```
['Words', 'Shirt', 'Blouse', 'Sweater', 'Swqatqr', 'Swwatwr', 'multipleeee', 'multiplqqee', 'multipleeqq', 'multiplwwee', 'multipleeww']
```

Prettyprint:

```
Words
Shirt
Blouse
Sweater
Swqatqr
Swwatwr
multipleeee
multiplqqee
multipleeqq
multiplwwee
multipleeww
```

I added `multipleeee` to demonstrate, how the replacement works: For `num = 2` it means the first two occurences are replaced, after them, the next two. So there is no intersection of the replaced parts. If you would want to have something like `['multiplqqee', 'multipleqqe', 'multipleeqq']`, you would have to store the position of the "first" occurence of `char`. You can then restore `pos` to that position in the `if multiples == num:`-block.

If you got further questions, feel free to ask. :)

Comment: Hey Dave, solution works!  Would love an explanation of how though :)  Also, is there an easy way to dictate how many letters in the string I want to replace (e.g. instead of one at a time, two at a time, etc)

Comment: This is incredibly clever -- hats off!  Thank you again for taking the time to explain.  That was very helpful in understand :)

Answer (score 1):

Because you need to replace letters one at a time, this doesn't sound like a good problem to solve with pandas, since pandas is about doing everything  at once (vectorized operations). I would dump out your DataFrame into a plain old list and use list operations:

```
words = DF.to_dict()["Words"].values()

for find, replace in reversed(sorted(mydict.items())):
    for word in words:
        occurences = word.count(find)
        if not occurences:
            print word
            continue
        start_index = 0
        for i in range(occurences):
            for replace_char in replace.split(","):
                modified_word = list(word)
                index = modified_word.index(find, start_index)
                modified_word[index] = replace_char
                modified_word = "".join(modified_word)
                print modified_word
            start_index = index + 1
```

Which gives:

```
Words
Shirt
Blousq
Blousw
Swqater
Swwater
Sweatqr
Sweatwr
Words
Shirt
Blouse
Swezter
```

Instead of printing the words, you can append them to a list and re-create a DataFrame if that's what you want to end up with.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looping, you need to update `s` at each cycle of the loop.  You also need to loop over v.

```
mydict = {"e":"q,w"}
s=deduped
for k, v in mydict.items():
     for j in v:
          s = s.replace(k, j)
```

Then reassign it to your dataframe:

```
df["Words"] = s
```

If you can write this as a function that takes in a 1d array (list, numpy array etc...), you can use df.apply to apply it to any column, using `df.apply()`.

Comment: Hey Adam -- Thanks for the response.  Code is just returning original column with no replacements with the following error: "SettingWithCopyWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_index,col_indexer] = value instead"

Comment: I'd recommend not using s['words'] in the loop as that will return the entire column of the dataframe as a reference.  What if you copy it: snew = copy.copy(s['words']).  It might be getting hung up because you are passing a reference to the actual column instead of create a new array, mutating it, and reassigning it.  Does this make sense?