# Find and replace for millions of rows with regex in Python

Tags: python, regex, performance, replace, find-replace

I have 2 set of data.

First one which serves as dictionary has two columns `keyword` and `id` and 180000 rows. Below is some sample data.

Also, note that some of the keyword are as small as 2 character and as big as 700 characters and there is no fixed length of the keywords. Although id has fixed pattern of 3 digit number with a hash symbol before and after the number.

```
keyword         id
salesman        #123#
painter         #486#
senior painter  #215#
```

Second file has one column which is `corpus` and it runs into 22 million records and length of each record varies between 10 to 1000. Below is sample data which can be considered as input.

```
corpus
I am working as a salesman. salesmanship is not my forte, however i have become a good at it
I have been a painter since i was 19
are you the salesman?
```

Output

```
corpus
I am working as a #123#. salesmanship is not my forte, however i have become a good at it
I have been a #486# since i was 19
are you the #123#?
```

Please note that i want to replace **complete word** and not overlapped words. so in the first sentence `salesman` was replaced with `#123#` where as `salesmanship` was not replaced with `#123#ship`. This requires me to add regular expression `'\b'` before and after the `keyword`. This is why Regex is important for the search function

So this is a search and replace operation for multi-million rows and has regex. I have read 
[Mass string replace in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1919096/mass-string-replace-in-python)
and
[Speed up millions of regex replacements in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42742810/speed-up-millions-of-regex-replacements-in-python-3), however it is taking me days to do this find and replace, which i can't afford as this is a weekly task. I want to be able to do this much faster. Below is my code

```
Id = df_dict.Id.tolist()
#convert to list with regex
keyword = [r'\b'+ x + r'\b' for x in df_dict.keyword]
#light on memory to clean file
del df_dict
#replace
df_corpus["corpus_text"].replace(keyword, Id, regex=False,inplace=True)
```

Comment: Parallelize it using `multiprocessing`.  If you have an 8-core machine you should be able to split the job into 8 or more parts and do them concurrently.

Comment: I have 4 core machine with 8 GB RAM, hence not the best option

Comment: Is writing C, C++, Java, etc an option?

Comment: I only know R, Python

Comment: If you check closely df_dict.Id.tolist() is pandas code df_dict is dataframe Id is name of column and tolist() is used like data_frame.column_name.tolist()

Comment: Out of curiosity, how are you mapping 180,000 rows to no more than 1000 IDs (because each ID is only 3 digits)?

Comment: This is just an example, real data has 9 numbers.

Comment: I've never used the algorithm or the library, but you should look into the [Aho-Corasick algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho-Corasick_algorithm) and the appropriately named [pyahocorasic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho-Corasick_algorithm) library.

Comment: @supersam654 there isn't any documentation on find and replace, although there is documentation for find operation https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyahocorasick/1.0.0#example